# Need to upgrade from docker to containerd for GKE version upgrade from v1.23 to v1.24

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, migrate, containerd

As per below mentioned script I have upgraded version runtime :from docker to containerd It changed from cos to cos_containerd as well, after updating inside the cluster its showing upgraded but when I am going to do cluster upgrade I am not able to perform

I have upgraded through below script for Migration from Docker to containerd node image

## For script you can follow below link

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/migrate-containerd#gcloud

as per script its showing some nodes need to be upgrade I have upgraded those nodes It changed from cos to cos_containerd as well, after updating inside the cluster its showing upgraded but when I am going to do cluster upgrade its showing like below in google console
[image]

What I need to do further,- is there any another step required to do?

Comment: Do those nodes belong to only one node pool?

Comment: No Siegfred V. different node pools

Comment: I have tried to replicate this on my end. Once all of the node pools are updated to Container-Optimized OS with containerd (cos_containerd), The prompt or recommendation is still present that it uses COS image but you can proceed on upgrading the cluster master version.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate this on my end. Once all of the node pools are updated to `Container-Optimized OS`with `containerd` (cos_containerd).

The prompt or recommendation is still present that it uses COS image but you can proceed on upgrading the cluster master version